# Azure Logic App - Concurrency Control Setting Not Available for "For Each" Loop

Tags: foreach, concurrency, azure-logic-apps

I want to ensure that my "For Each" loop runs sequentially as there are variables in the loop that should be protected from other threads.  When I initially setup this flow, I was given the option to turn Concurrency Control on and set the Degree of Parallelism to 1.  However, when I click settings for my "For Each" loop now, the option does not exist.  I have noticed that for a number of my apps the option is gone (but remains for others).  Why does this happen?

[image]
[image]

Additional info:

- These apps are triggered by "Recurrence"
- Changing browser does not help

Comment: I did this yesterday and confirmed it is still working today. I would put in a support ticket. Aside: given the global nature of variables in Logic Apps, the default behavior of for each has always bothered me.

Comment: @joel, totally agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from our end we could able to view the concurrency control settings for all the **recurrence/polling triggers**. However, one workaround that you can do is to add concurrency control over code-view of your logic app. Below is the code for recurrence/polling triggers.

```
"runtimeConfiguration": {
    "concurrency": {
      "repetitions": 16
    }
  }
```

Below is the code view of my for each loop.

```
"foreach": "<RECURRENCE VARIABLE>",
  "runAfter": {
    "Initialize_variable": [
      "Succeeded"
    ]
  },
  "runtimeConfiguration": {
    "concurrency": {
      "repetitions": 16
    }
  },
  "type": "Foreach"
}
```

Alternatively, you can submit a support ticket regarding the missing feature from [Azure support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/).

Comment: Thanks.  Something I noticed is that I can set the value from code view, however, after saving, if I enter the designer view I immediately have unsaved changes (despite making 0 changes since saving) and when I click the "</> Code View" tab the setting is removed.  If I leave and discard the unsaved changes, the setting is back.  So it seems that the designer view is wiping it out.  I have opened a support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

I received a call late last night from Microsoft. They anticipate a hotfix soon.

In the meantime, they have a workaround. Create a variable array with `[1]` in it. Create a new loop with the concurrency of one iterating on the workaround loop. Add your existing loop inside the new loop and it works!

FYI: Every time you save it you will have to re-add the concurrency controls via code view if you go with the accepted answer.

Comment: I have not received a confirmation of any fix, but I am no longer seeing the setting removed on save and I can now access the settings from designer.

Comment: UPDATE: I just received confirmation that the issue is resolved.